# AngularJS and DOM: Get element inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, ng-view

I'm simply trying to get the height of an element in my ng-view, using DOM, in my AngularJS controller.

I am getting a `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementById is not a function` on the following code located in my AngularJS controller.

```
// I do a hardcoded timeout for now to wait for ng-view to load.
setTimeout(function(){ 
  var theView = document.getElementsByClassName("view-container")[0].getElementById("myView").getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
}, 10000);
```

Here's what my HTML looks like:

```
<div class="view-container">
    <ng-view class="view-frame ng-scope" autoscroll="" id="myView">
        <div class="container ng-scope">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-view>
</div>
```

I've checked my spelling for `getElementById` many times. Am I missing some weird thing how AngularJS, ng-view, and DOM just do not like to work together? Or is there a "Angular" way to get the height of an element in my ng-view instead of using DOM?

Comment: Just to explain your error: `getElementById` is a method on `document`. `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. You can't call `getElementById` on an element.

Comment: @Antiga I see. I haven't much experience in DOM -- how would you suggest I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are chaining a bunch of selectors together. You could just give that `div` an `id` and `getElementById`. Or the way it is now, (assuming there are no other elements with the container `class`), you could chop off the whole first part and just call `getElementsByClassName("container")[0];`. You don't need to target and then re-target.

Comment: The html within `<ng-view>` is dynamic, and I have several `container`s. I think my target`container` is always the third container: I'll give this a try real quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call getElementById on an element, only the document supports that function.

Just do:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
  var theView = document.getElementById("myView").getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
}, 10000);
```

Comment: Actually, [they do] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Fair enough +Public Display Name. Also, fairly off-topic, I think `ng-view` has a callback for when it's loaded? Would certainly be better than the `timeout`. This is more for OP, I know that wasn't his question.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked. Don't know why someone downvoted you for this.

Comment: @Antiga, Yes perhaps, but that would be a different question